# Dual-input for 2 TextFields in JavaFX on one machine

Tags: java, javafx, keyboard, user-input, textfield

I am working on a project in Java using JavaFX. The project is for a Cafe notification system that has a front end for the customers and has a front end for the cooks and I am running a dual display where one display has the user front end and another display for the cooks front end. The problem is that if there are 2 keyboards connected to the raspberry pi, both input will be in the same TextField because you can't select more than one TextField on a single machine.

What I think could work is that the keyboard for cooks is just the number pad and the users have a normal keyboard without a numberpad. So if there was a way to grab input from the numberpad (since they have different key codes then the numbers on the top of a keyboard) and enter text into the cook TextField without the window being in focus, that would solve my issue I just don't know how to go about that. The user input would just be entered normally since it will be focused on the user UI and they can click for different text fields.

Is that method possible? Is there a better method? Or is this whole thing not feasible and I should just switch to 2 separate raspberry pi's? (please see if it is possible before going straight to 2 devices)

For reference the github project is here: https://github.com/thatoneguy43/CafeBuzzerSystem

I'm hoping I didn't leave any important information out, this is my first post here. If you need any more info from me or have any questions ask away.

Comment: Some searching gave me the term "multi-seating". That may be what you're looking for.

Comment: the idea of different areas of the keyboard sounds feasible (as long as you handle the events yourself). however you will have a problem with the special keys: enter, del, backspace ... so it is better to think of virtual keyboards for each terminal

Comment: now I think you can use a modified keyboard (holding ctrl or alt pressed)